# Centering all elements that are dynamically added to div

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, alignment

So I have this div:

```
<div id="termSheetPrinted">

</div>
```

This div is filled through this method:

```
function GenerateTermSheet()
        {
            var urlString = "<%= System.Web.VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/mvc/Indications.cfc/RenderPartialTermSheetView")%>";
            var jsonNickname = 
                {
                    id : GetGUIDValue(),
                    viewName : 'Nickname'
                }
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: urlString,
                    data: jsonNickname,
                    success: function(data) {
                        $('#termSheetPrinted').append(data);
                    }
                });
            $('#termSheetPopup input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function(){
                var checkedName = $(this).attr("name");
                var json = 
                {
                    id : GetGUIDValue(),
                    viewName : checkedName
                }
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: urlString,
                    data: json,
                    success: function(data) {
                        $('#termSheetPrinted').append(data);
                    }
                });
            })
            $('#termSheetPopup').dialog('close');
            $('#termSheetPrinted').dialog('open');
        }
```

So partial views are fetched from the server and are appended to the div as they come back successfully. However, everything is left aligned in the div. I tried adding a style to the div they are appended to like this:

```
<div id="termSheetPrinted" style="text-align:center;">

</div>
```

It didn't work though, and I'm assuming the reason is because the other elements are added after the initial div is rendered. Basically, the user experience is that the `termSheetPrinted` div pops up on a JQuery dialog, and as it's open the other elements are populated in real time in front of them, even though the code was not really meant to work this way, that's the way it works.

Know of any way I can center all these elements coming in, in the div?

EDIT:

Example of a view that is appended to the div. This is returned from my controller returning a view, then the Ajax call grabs it and appends it:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<Chatham.Web.Models.Indications.ModelBase>" %>

<table id="nickNameBTS">
    <tr id="tr5">
        <td id="td7" style="text-align: right;">
            Indication Nickname:
        </td>
        <td id="td8" colspan="3">
            <%= Html.Encode(Model.STPData.ProjectName)%>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#nickNameBTS").bubble({ width: 400, title: 'Nickname' });
        });

    </script>
```

Comment: "I'm assuming the reason is because the other elements are added after the initial div is rendered". Nope, CSS will affect the inside of the DIV *dynamically*. So if you add content to your div, then it should be styled.

Comment: It should right? I'm not sure why it's not though. I was thinking the same thing.

Comment: I added an answer. Hope it works but if not, I would give this advice (as it doesn't depend on Ajax) : focus on the final data. Load the content, save the page and work on that offline version, then you can target the problem and fix it :) -I assume you know Firebug?-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add another container inside termSheetPrinted, center it and insert all elements inside that container.

```
<div id="termSheetPrinted">
  <div id="content" style="width: 500px; margin: 0 auto;"></div>
</div>
```

Note, that in order to center horizontally using margin: 0 auto, you need to specify an absolute width.  What this will do is center the content container (and all its content) within termSheetPrinted.

By the way, I advise against inline styling as this example shows.  Please use CSS files.

Answer (score 2):

The fact that the inner elements are added with Ajax shouldn't affect how they are rendered, because modifying the DOM should trigger a reflow.

`text-align:center` works only on inline elements, or any element but only on IE5 and IE6.
For *block* elements, you have to fix the `width` of your element, and define auto `margin`.

```
#elementToCenter { 
  margin-left: auto; 
  margin-right: auto; 
  width: 960px;
}
```

Combine this with text-align to fix IE behavior. Here are the [solutions for centering elements](http://css-discuss.incutio.com/wiki/Centering_Block_Element) depending on your code.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
<div id="termSheetPrinted" style="text-align:center; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto">

</div>
```

See also: http://dorward.me.uk/www/centre/

Comment: Can you provide an example of the data that is appended to #termSheetPrinted?

Comment: Edited. Posted the .aspx view

Comment: The returned data is not valid HTML this will mess up your rendering (or is this some kind of IE only feature executing C# on the client side or something??).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're correct (that it's not being styled correctly due to it's coming in to the DOM late), the simplest answer I can think of is to reapply the style after the call to `.append`. You could do this with a single line `.css('text-align','center');` after the `.append` call in the `success` parameter:

```
          $.ajax({
                ...
                success: function(data) {
                    $('#termSheetPrinted').append(data);
                    $('#termSheetPrinted').css('text-align','center');
                }
```

If it's not being centered for another reason, though, this won't fix it.

Comment: Then you've got a different problem than the one you think you have :) Use tools (Firefox: [web developer toolbar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/web-developer/), Safari: debug tools (prefs>advanced>enable debug menu)) to see what styles apply to the text you're discussing, and try to see where they're coming from.

Comment: For reference, "coming in to the DOM late" is a non-existent issue. CSS styles and classes apply to all DOM elements, regardless of when or how they were created.